After login using cy.origin I am not logged in
I'm struggling with login using cy.origin. I've try use cy.session, but after session the page is log out.
Here is my commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (username, password) => {
  cy.session(
    [username, password],
    () => {
      cy.visit(Cypress.env("dmvs")); // Navigate to your application
      cy.get(
        "button[class='p-link layout-header-button layout-header-button-with-label']"
      ).click();
      cy.get("a[href='login/isds']").click();

      // Login via the external service
      cy.origin(
        "https://siteexample",
        { args: { username, password } },
        ({ username, password }) => {
          cy.get("#Ecom_User_ID").type(username);
          cy.get("#Ecom_Password").click({ force: true }).type(password);
          cy.get("button[type='submit'][form='IDPLogin']").click();
          cy.wait(3000);
          cy.get("#atsOk").click();
          cy.wait(3000);
        }
      );
    },
  );
});

Here is my cy.js file
describe("Authenticate", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.login(Cypress.env("ds_username"), Cypress.env("ds_password"))
  });

  it("Show homepage once logged in", () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("dmvs"));
  });
});

In my config file i have
e2e: {
    watchForFileChanges: false,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 5000,
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
  },

Thank you for help :)
I try log in on website. Website using redirect for login. After successful login and after redirect back to my page I'm not logged in.
